# Get key using value from a Map containing duplicate keys or values

Tags: java, dictionary, bimap

I have a Map having duplicate values. I now want to get the key using value without iterating through all the Map.Entries. I have more than 500 entries in the map. I do not want to iterate the whole map each time.

I thought of using BiMap of google collections. But, BiMap does not support duplicate keys. Could anyone suggest on what other thirdparty library can be used to solve this?

Update:
The map contains duplicate values and it's loaded from a text file containing key value pairs.

Comment: According to the Javadoc for `Map`: "If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value". Soo... are you sure it supports duplicate keys ?

Comment: Keys are unique; consider using a collection of values.

Comment: @SoboLAN I have the map with duplicate values. Map is loaded from a text file having key value pairs. When I use copyOf method of BiMap, it does not allow for reason of having duplicate values.

Comment: @John So you mean duplicate values and not duplicate keys right ? then please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a Map

...well, there's your problem! It sounds like the data doesn't quite fit the limitations of a BiMap. Consider maintaining a different ordered collection of your data encapsulated as tuples (or a pair of ordered collections).

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [ListMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html) and then use [Multimaps.invertFrom()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#invertFrom%28com.google.common.collect.Multimap,%20M%29) to get the inverse mapping.